# Google maps img marker gets transparent pixels

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Maps JS API v3 to place image marker on map.

Here is JSFiddle with illustration of a problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/t99ars8L/1/

```
/*
 * declare map as a global variable
 */
var map;

/*
 * use google maps api built-in mechanism to attach dom events
 */
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

  /*
   * create map
   */
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  /*
   * create infowindow (which will be used by markers)
   */
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  /*
   * marker creater function (acts as a closure for html parameter)
   */
  function createMarker(options, html) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
    if (html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(options.map, this);
      });
    }
    return marker;
  }

  /*
   * add markers to map
   */
  var marker0 = createMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    map: map,
    icon: "http://html.accuraten.com/doubleup-html/public/img/map-marker@2x.png"
  }, "<h1>Marker 0</h1><p>This is the home marker.</p>");
});
```

When you open this code on non-Retina desktop screen (for example OSX/Safari) and zoom back and forth, you could see transparent pixels on this marker.

It looks like this
http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn185/vladgenie/%20%202015-11-16%20%2012.51.13_zpspjir2ip5.png

Why this is happening? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Tested on OS X Safari & Chrome and I can't reproduce what you show in the image.

Comment: @mrupsidown Do you have retina screen? I can reproduce on old & new MBP with non-retina setting. On Safari only.

Comment: Same here. Don't see issue. Tested on Safari/OSX. Can you make sure you don't have any other script, plugin or extension causing map to load slowly? Because what you describe as transparent pixels, I assume are the map tiles not yet loaded. Try loading it in Private Window and see if the issue persists.